# Xpath using contains after an unclosed br tag

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am testing the following markup using xpath and selenium:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        123
        <br>
        456
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and while this xpath works/matches:

```
//table/tbody/tr/td[contains(text(),'123')]
```

This one does not match:

```
//table/tbody/tr/td[contains(text(),'456')]
```

I'm just using "find" in chrome developer tools to test my xpath expressions so I suppose it's not a selenium question but my eventual intent is to make a function that returns true if a value is found in the table, false if not found.

My guess is that the unclosed `<br>` is messing things up but I dont have the ability to change the markup so I need to play the cards that I was dealt. Does anyone have any ideas of how to find out if a value exists in the table with similar markup?

I expect that I might have to get all values in every cell (which hopefully returns the stuff before and after the `<br>`) and then loop through them in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not that the `br` tag is "unclosed". In fact the browser has parsed that empty `<br>` element and your XPath is operating over a data model which is indistinguishable from one that an XML parser would produce from either `<br/>` or `<br></br>`.

The result is that you have a `td` element node which contains 3 child nodes:

- a text node `123`
- an empty `<br>` element
- another text node `456`

The problem you're seeing is that the `contains` function is converting its first argument `text()` into a string, as if by a call to the `string` function, and the rule here is that the string value of a set of nodes is defined to be the string value of the member of that set which is *first* in document order; in your example that is the text node `123`. So the second (and any subsequent) text node would be ignored. Once again, that would be true whether the intervening element were a `br`, or an `img` or a `span` or anything else.

One solution, if you want to check if the `td` contains the string 456, and you don't care about how that string is broken up by child elements, or whether it might be nested inside some other element (e.g. `<span>456</span>`) is to pass the entire string value of the `td` element as the first parameter to `contains`:

```xpath
//table/tbody/tr/td[contains(.,'456')]
```

If you only wanted to know if the string `456` occurred in a text node which was a direct child of the `td` (and ignore the case where it was nested inside a `span` inside that `td`, for instance), you could use an XPath like this:

```xpath
//table/tbody/tr/td[text()[contains(.,'456')]]
```

(Read this as "a td which has a text node child, which in turn contains the string 456")

Answer (score -1):

Your assumption is correct. The `<br>` is causing the second locator to fail but there is a way around it.

`text()` gives you specifically the text inside the element itself. You can alternatively use `.` which basically "flattens" text inside all descendant elements. So, you can shorten both your locators to

```
//table/tbody/tr/td[contains(.,'123')]
//table/tbody/tr/td[contains(.,'456')]
```

and both will work.

---

NOTE: Your XPath might be overly specific. For example, by specifying the `tbody` layer you are excluding table headings. If you ONLY want to search the body of the table, then you're good.